Causal inference of impact of a university bankruptcy
I have taken one introductory course in causal inference but I'm very new to this.
I have one problem I'm thinking of tackling. There are 124 electoral districts in Ontario. ED boundaries were the same from 2018 to 2022, but there was a high-profile university bankruptcy in one remote district in 2021. I would like to estimate the causal effect of that bankruptcy on the incumbent party's electoral support. In effect, how much of a hit did the governing party take because it oversaw this basically unpopular and controversial bankruptcy.
Thinking this through, the district was a northern district, with a university in its boundaries plus with a significant French-Canadian population that was served by the university.
So, would I do a difference-in-difference strategy with a dichotomous variable for each district (1 if northern, 0 if not) , perhaps a continuous variable for employment in the university sector in the district (# of professors in the district) and a continuous variable for proportion of French Canadians? Have I got that about right?
Thanks.

Does the bankruptcy of this one institution affect one district or many? Put differently, does the “northern” dummy represent a collection of districts or just that one northern district?

It is not really known; the university is housed only in one district but I guess I would like to know if there was a drop in the university district could it actually be a product of some unknown region-wide trend that affected similar northern districts as well, beyond the university.

What do the northern and southern trends look like with respect to electoral support pre-2021? Or at the very least what do you think you will see?

The boundaries of the districts changed substantially between 2014 and 2018. 95% of districts changed boundaries and 17 new districts were added. So getting a sense of the trend prior to 2018 is hard, if not impossible. Maybe not impossible, but it would require a lot of judgment calls.
The boundaries between 2018 and 2021 are stable, so there is a fair before-after comparison. That said, I mean I clearly could compute province-wide trends, and the district where the university is is clearly identifiable. I could take a stab at it and just note the problem of the boundary changes.
